# How to check how many times there was borrowing in a subtraction equation with base 1000 numbers?

Tags: java, performance, radix, subtraction, processing-efficiency

Lets say I have two numbers in base 1000 that are both very large(maybe  5000, base 1000, digits). In addition, I want to subtract the two large numbers. I also want to check how many times the program borrowed from the next place. You can get more information on borrowing and how to do it [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-borrow-when-subtracting.html). One idea I had on how to do this is to check each of the same individual place values on each number. If the first numbers value was smaller than the second number than increment a variable which, in the end, would be the amount of times there was borrowing. This is a fairly inefficient idea because I would have to analyze 5000 different digits with another 5000 digits, and the idea could use lots of improvement. All answers on **what is the most efficient way to count the amount of times there was borrowing in a subtraction equation with large numbers in base 1000** would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: If the radix (base 1000) of number B is larger than number A in the original number, it has to borrow. Iterate over both numbers at the same time, count the occurrences, and that'll get you a result. Not sure if that is mathematically correct, so i wont post it as an answer.

Comment: is there a more efficient way than to individually check each digit?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll leave that question open for someone else to answer :)

Comment: How do you represent your numbers? As in, what data structure are you using?

Comment: I would represent the numbers in a char list

Comment: There aren't any language features that let you work on char lists as a single entity. You may find API methods that work on char arrays, but they themselves are implemented by iterating through each char.